# Able to copy folders but not files to directory

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, centos, samba

I am currently using CentOS 6.5 and trying to share files over a samba share. On the other machine is Windows 8 x64. I am able to transfer folders from Windows to CentOS over without issues but however, when I try to copy a single file over to CentOS, I get permission denied error on Windows.

Permissions of the folder is as follows:

```
drwxrwxrwx.   5 user01 smbusers  4096 Feb 28 23:23 srv
```

And the smb.conf:

```
[srv]
        comment = Data
        path = /srv
        browseable = yes
        writable = yes
        read only = no
        valid users = @smbusers
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        create mask = 0775
        directory mask = 0775
```

Can I know what is the issue here? I have been troubleshooting for quite some time and can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As /srv was a system folder, SELinux prevented me from writing directly into the folder. So you need to enter this command before it will work:

```
setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
```

after this you should be able to write without any issues into any system folders that you have shared through samba.